# Using a bootstrap.css style for new account creation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a simple webpage that uses `bootstrap.css` for styling. It does not seem to work. I specified a "horizontal" layout, with the labels to the left of the fields, and the right edges of the labels aligned, but the output shows up as stacked, with the labels above the fields.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post"
            enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            action="/auth/page/account/newaccount">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Register a new account</legend>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="PPMN5nK3IL">
                <div class="control-group clearfix required ">
                    <label class="control-label" for="h2">Username</label>
                    <div class="controls input">
                        <input id="h2" name="f2" type="text" required value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group clearfix required ">
                    <label class="control-label" for="h3">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls input">
                        <input id="h3" name="f3" type="email" required="" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group clearfix required ">
                    <label class="control-label" for="h4">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls input">
                        <input id="h4" name="f4" type="password" required="" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group clearfix required ">
                    <label class="control-label" for="h5">Confirm</label>
                    <div class="controls input">
                        <input id="h5" name="f5" type="password" required="" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <input class="btn primary btn-large" type="submit"
                        value="Create New Account">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <script src="netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work in http://jsfiddle.net/rP8XJ/.  I think you may have some other css settings that are overriding Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `//` as part of your stylesheet link.

Change it to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

Same applies to the script tags at the bottom.

Also, note that you need to include the `jQuery` file before the `bootstrap` file as `bootstrap` depends on several `jQuery` features.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that I need the `//` in absolute URLs.